# Thin horizontal white lines appear when presenting a SwiftUI view embedded in a Hosting Controller from UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I have a SwiftUI view called a paywall view.

I create and present it from UIKit view controller like this:

```
let paywallView = PaywallView()
let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: paywallView)
hostingController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(hostingController, animated: true)
```

Everything works fine and as expected, however, during the presentation transition / animation, these horizontal thin white lines appear and they go away once the animation is complete.

**During the transition**
[image: SwiftUI Hosting Controller present from UIKit]

**After the transition**
[image: SwiftUI Hosting Controller present from UIKit]

Side note: There is no navigation bar, navigation view or navigation stack in the SwiftUI view.

Any idea why this happens and how to solve this ?